# How do I get text of label when changed to server side?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to assign the text of a label to a hidden field when not post back but I fail. This is what I done.

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
            Dim structPayperiod As strcPayperiodDet


            structPayperiod = objTimeSystem.getCurrentPayPeriod()
            hdnPayperiodseq.Value = structPayperiod.Payperiodid
            hdnPayPeriodStartDt.Value = structPayperiod.startdate.ToString

            lblPayPeriodStartDt.Text = structPayperiod.startdate

            displayPayrollIdOrgs(objTimeSystem.getPayrollIDOrgs())

            grd_Employees.Visible = False

            RptErrorsMessages.DataSource = objTimeSystem.getErrorMessages()
            RptErrorsMessages.DataBind()
        Else
            hdnPayPeriodStartDt.Value = lblPayPeriodStartDt.Text.ToString

        End If
```

Problem comes in else clause where the value doesn't get update with new label value. lblPayPeriodStartDt.Text is not updating.

The value of label is date and it updates every time I change the date using calender control on client side. But, the value of the label doesn't refresh with that value.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblPayPeriodStartDt" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<img src="../Images/calendar.gif" class="clsCursorHand" alt="" title="Select Pay Period"
                            onclick="Javascript:PayPeriodsPayroll('<%=lblPayPeriodStartDt.ClientId %>',event);"/>
```

Comment: is your calendar control doing a postback everytime you change the date?

Comment: Can you post the code for `PayPeriodsPayroll` js function where you are assigning value for the `lblPayPeriodStartDt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not going to get the value of the `<asp:Label` you modified on client side at the code behind. If I'm correct ASP.NET label is rendered as a span element in the client side:

I think that only the controls that are rendered as input controls and values changed at client side are updated on viewstate, so your only resort is to stick to the hidden field.

You just have to do the other way around.

**1**.Pass the hidden field to the js function and update the value of the hidden field at the client side in your js function `PayPeriodsPayroll` like below

```
 function PayPeriodsPayroll (hdnObj)
 {
   var hdnPayPeriod = document.getElementById(hdnObj);
   hdnPayPeriod.val('the value you want to set');
 }
```

Then in your pageload

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
   ....
Else
    // update label with the hidden field value if you need it
    lblPayPeriodStartDt.Text = hdnPayPeriodStartDt.Value
End If
```

Comment: Thank you very much..this time I just passed the value of hidden field instead of label  in JS function, it worked..sorry for late response as I don't have access to code over weekend.

Answer (score 1):

surely you are not posting back to the server every time you change the date in the calendar  control.
You can do a postback to the server from javascript using the `__doPostback() function.`
see this link: 
[__doPostback function example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667531/doPostBack-function)

Comment: thank you, yes I wasn't post backing on date change..this helped.